# Height animation messing with the page scroll position

Tags: css, hover, css-animations

I need to make an element which has a hidden button that appears on hover. I'm achieving this by making an animation with the button height, but the first element of the row keeps making the page go up.

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>

      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem>
        <h1>Lorem Sint et id ad ut proident.</h1>
        <div className="button">Button</div>
      </GridItem>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

  margin: 17.2rem 0;
`;

const GridItem = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: grey;

  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;

  div {
    -webkit-transition: height 400ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: height 400ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: height 400ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: height 400ms ease-out;
    transition: height 400ms ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    will-change: height;

    background-color: white;
  }

  :hover {
    .button {
      height: 56px;

      animation: fadeIn 400ms;
      -webkit-animation: fadeIn 400ms;
      -moz-animation: fadeIn 400ms;
      -o-animation: fadeIn 400ms;
      -ms-animation: fadeIn 400ms;

      @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: You need to put your code in the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know. But wouldn't be better if there was a link to codebox too?

Comment: That's up to you. But external resources die and can't be guaranteed to be in the same state as when you first posted, so we ask that you put the code here to avoid that. (Also deals with annoying licensing issues.)